# How to make python's built-in print function, make a label on a gui (I am making a REPL) instead of printing to console?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, read-eval-print-loop

The title says it all, this is what I have currently (bare start). I am going to overwrite all `sys.std__` functions that way I don't have to manually overwrite functions like print, input... I am unsure on how to actually *place* the label because I don't have the required properties from Gui class.

```py
class ModifiedPrint:
    def __init__(self):
        self.old = sys.stdout

    def write(self, text):
        sys.stdout = self.old
        print(text) # just a start
        sys.stdout = self

    def flush(self):
        self.old.flush()

sys.stdout = ModifiedPrint()
```

The entire code: (including the Gui class mentioned) https://pastebin.com/9J9BiFGr

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import sys

class GUIPrint:
    def __init__(self, text_widget:tk.Text):
        self.old_stdout = sys.stdout
        self.text = text_widget

    def write(self, data:str):
        # Insert the text in the text widget
        self.text.insert("end", data)

    def __enter__(self):
        # Enter the `with` statement
        sys.stdout = self
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        # Exit the `with` statement
        sys.stdout = self.old_stdout


def function():
    print("Hello world")

root = tk.Tk()

text_widget = tk.Text(root)
text_widget.pack()
gui_printer = GUIPrint(text_widget)

print("Normal stdout")
with gui_printer:
    print("Inside the GUI")
    function()
print("Normal stdout")

root.mainloop()
```

Everything inside the `with` statement gets printed in the text widget. It isn't a good idea to always hold `sys.stdout` so I release it when the `with` statement exits.

Please note that I used a `tk.Text` instead of `tk.Label`s. It is much easier to do it this way.

Comment: Thanks for a answer, how would I use this when I don't know if the code inside `exec()` is a print statement or not? I may be missing something here, I barely ever use the with keyword / statement (I'll go read up on it in a minute).

Comment: @ammarsys just put all of the code that might/will have a print inside it in the `with` statement. I updated my code with a better example. Even if you use `print` function another function/from inside an `exec`, it will still be printed on the GUI as long as it is inside the `with` statement.